# Android studio never ending build

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I developed app with React Native. I tried build but building does not end.

[show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucAkw.png)

Task :app:multiDexListRelease
Task :app:mergeReleaseJavaResource

These tasks have been processed for 17 minutes. Is this normal?

app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
   applicationId "com.app"
   minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
   targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
   versionCode 1
   versionName "1.0"
   multiDexEnabled true
   missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle file do you have the following:

```
android{
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 21
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
  ...
}
```

multiDexEnabled needs to be true in order for these gradle commands to run.

Comment: my defaultConfig like below.     defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
    }